# How can I optimize the code for big QStringList?

Tags: qt, sorting, optimization, qstring, qstringlist

The following code does not seem to finish in tolerable time if list2 contains more than 200,000 entries.

```
    QStringList list1; 
    QStringList list2=getalist();
    int count=list2.count();
    for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        QString e=list2[j];
        if(!list1.contains(e,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        {
            list1<<e;
        }
    }
```

What is the bottleneck and how can I optimize it?

Comment: For starters don't use QList before Qt6

Comment: QStrings are heavyweights, you're creating one in a loop. It might get optimized away, or it might not. I wouldn't take the bet if your code isn't performing well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottleneck is the choice of `QStringList` as the container for that task. It is a `QList<QString>` and I believe it uses linear search to  implement the function `contains`.

The best solution would be to use a tree-based container like std::set or a hash based container like `QSet` (yes, it it hash based contrary to the std::set). From Qt [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qset.html):

> QSet is one of Qt's generic container classes. It stores values in
> an unspecified order and provides **very fast lookup** of the values.
> Internally, QSet is implemented as a QHash.

Comment: After switching to QSet, the code finishes in a blink. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to update `list1` to be the union of all unique elements in `list1` and `list2` subject to a case insensitive compare.  So something like (untested)...

```
QStringList list1;
QStringList list2 = getalist();

struct case_insensitive_compare {
    bool operator() (const QString &l, const QString &r) const
    {
        return l.compare(r, Qt::CaseInsensitive) < 0;
    }
};

std::set<QString, case_insensitive_compare> set1(list1.begin(), list1.end());
set1.insert(list2.begin(), list2.end());
list1 = QStringList(set1.begin(), set1.end());
```

Comment: @deW1 Ah, right.  It's possible that `list1` already has duplicates.  I'll wait for the OP to comment.

Comment: @G.M. Your code is also great, especially that it can deal with the case insensitive issue. The redundant entries in the list are also removed. But the line "list1 = QStringList(set1.begin(), set1.end());" cannot compile on my machine, maybe because my qt version is too old (Qt 5.12). So I adopted Vasilij's answer. Thank you!